# Reader monad in Scala: return, local, and sequence

Tags: scala, monads, scalaz, reader-monad

I'm using the `Reader` monad in Scala as provided by the [scalaz](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz) library. I'm familiar with this monad [as defined in Haskell](https://wiki.haskell.org/All_About_Monads#The_Reader_monad). The problem is that I cannot find the functions equivalent to `return`, `local`, and `sequence` (among others).

Currently I use constructs that I do not like since I'm repeating myself or making my code a bit obscure.

Regarding `return`, I'm currently using:

```
Reader{_ => someValue}
```

I'd rather just use a construct like `unit(someValue)`, but I could not find anything on the internet. There are tutorials like [this one](http://blog.originate.com/blog/2013/10/21/reader-monad-for-dependency-injection/) that use the approach above, and which I consider not optimal.

Regarding `local` I also have to do something similar: instead of typing something like: `local f myReader` I have to unfold its definition:

```
Reader{env => myReader.run(f(env))
```

Finally, sequence is a bit closer to what I would expect (being a Haskell refugee doing Scala):

```
readers: List[Reader[Env, T]]
readerTs: Reader[Env, List[T]] = readers.sequenceU
```

My problem with this implementation is that, being relatively new to Scala, the type of `sequenceU`

```
final class TraverseOps[F[_],A] private[syntax](val self: F[A])(implicit val F: Traverse[F]) extends Ops[F[A]] {
    //...
    def sequenceU(implicit G: Unapply[Applicative, A]): G.M[F[G.A]]
```

appears like rather obscure, and seems like black magic. Ideally I would like to use a `sequence` operations on Monads.

Is there a better translation of these constructs to Scala available on scalaz or similar library? I'm not married to any Functional library for Scala, so any solution using other libraries will do, although I'd rather have an answer using scalaz, since I already implemented my code using it.

Comment: Haskell to Scala - I pity you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make the things simpler, I fill in some types. Changing them to defs with generic types should still work. 
Also I extracted the `ReaderInt` type, to avoid confusion with type lambdas.

**return / pure / point**

Scala does not have automatic typeclass resolution, so you need to provide them implicitly. For `Kleisli` (being a monad transformer for reader), 
`Kleisli[Id, ?, ?]` is enough

```
 implicit val KA = scalaz.Kleisli.kleisliIdApplicative[Int]
 type ReaderInt[A] = Kleisli[Id.Id, Int, A]

 val alwaysHello = KA.point("hello")
```

or with imported syntax:

```
  import scalaz.syntax.applicative._  
  val alwaysHello = "hello".point[ReaderInt]
```

So as a general rule, you

1) import the applicative intance, which usually located in `scalaz.std.something.somethingInstance`

2) `import scalaz.syntax.something._`

3) then you can write `x.point[F]`, where `F` is your applicative.

**local**

Not sure, that it answers your question, but `Kleisli` has a `local` method.

```
val f: String ⇒ Int = _.length
val alwaysEleven = alwaysHello local f
```

**sequencing**

The same way, you are free to choose to use `syntax` for or to specify type classes explicitly.

```
  import scalaz.std.list.listInstance
  val initial: List[ReaderInt[String]] = ???  
  val sequenced: ReaderInt[List[String]] = Traverse[List].sequence[ReaderInt, String](initial) 

  import scalaz.syntax.traverse._
  val z = x.sequence[ReaderInt, String]
```

I prefer not to use `sequenceU`, which uses `Unapply` typelcass to infer the `G` type, because sometimes scala has troubles of figuring out the right one.
And I personally do not find it messy to put in some types myself.

It may worth to look into [cats](https://github.com/typelevel/cats), though it does not have much yet.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I like the improvements in my code your suggestion brings. I just want to understand everything that is happening under the hood, but that will take some time I guess.

Comment: I'm amazed by how much accidental complexity I'm encountering to understand the implementation of a relatively simple concept such as the Reader Monad in Scala. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38619516/scala-question-marks-in-type-parameters/38619906#38619906

Comment: I agree that type lambdas (without kind projector) make code unnecessary convoluted. But the way you bring typeclasses and syntax in - is not so bad, especially when you get used to it. If you give me some time, I will update the answer, to clarify a bit what happens under the hood.

Comment: I really appreciate it. In the meantime I'm walking around the scalaz implementation. Quite lost though ...

Comment: I'm deriving some questions from your answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38622081/scalaz-how-does-scalaz-syntax-applicative-works-its-magic