# Scala: question marks in type parameters

Tags: scala, scalaz, type-parameter

I'm trying to understand the following piece of code (from the Scalaz library):

```
def kleisliIdApplicative[R]: Applicative[Kleisli[Id, R, ?]] = ...
```

I'm assuming that a type of the form `T[P0, ?]` is a type-constructor that takes a parameter. However I'm no able to find documentation that explains the usage of question marks in type parameters.

A related question is what is the difference between the question mark and an underscore?

Is there a place where all this is well-documented?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The question mark syntax comes from a compiler plugin called [kind-projector](https://github.com/non/kind-projector).

You can see it being included in the scalaz build here: https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/blob/series/7.3.x/project/build.scala#L310

The plugin translates

```
Kleisli[Id, R, ?]
```

into (roughly)

```
({type L[A] = Kleisli[Id, R, A]})#L
```

which is a rather convoluted way (but unfortunately the only way in Scala) of expressing a type lambda, i.e. a partially applied type constructor.

Comment: What are you denoting here with `#L`? This expression does not compile for me in Scala 2.11

Comment: @Matthias L is the type member defined inside the anonymous type (i.e. the {} block). It should compile, what error do you get?

Comment: `<console>:1: error: ';' expected but '#' found.`
`({type L[A] = Either[Int, A]})#L`
                              ^

Comment: i.e. it trips over the `#`

Comment: syntax looks correct, you may be using it in the wrong context? Also refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8736164/what-are-type-lambdas-in-scala-and-what-are-their-benefits

Comment: Ah got it--I assumed you could reference the enclosed type from any context via `#`, but it only works inside a type argument list `[A, B, ...]`. Thanks.