# Scalaz: how does `scalaz.syntax.applicative._` works its magic

Tags: scala, scalaz, applicative, reader-monad

This question is related to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38524384/reader-monad-in-scala-return-local-and-sequence), where I was trying to understand how to use the reader monad in Scala.

In the answer the autor uses the following code for getting an instance of `ReaderInt[String]`:

```
import scalaz.syntax.applicative._
val alwaysHello2: ReaderInt[String] = "hello".point[ReaderInt]
```

Which mechanisms does Scala use to resolve the type of the expression `"hello".point[ReaderInt]` so that it uses the right `point` function?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A good first step any time you're trying to figure out something like this is to use the reflection API to desugar the expression:

```
scala> import scalaz.Reader, scalaz.syntax.applicative._
import scalaz.Reader
import scalaz.syntax.applicative._

scala> import scala.reflect.runtime.universe.{ reify, showCode }
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe.{reify, showCode}

scala> type ReaderInt[A] = Reader[Int, A]
defined type alias ReaderInt

scala> showCode(reify("hello".point[ReaderInt]).tree)
res0: String = `package`.applicative.ApplicativeIdV("hello").point[$read.ReaderInt](Kleisli.kleisliIdMonadReader)
```

(You generally don't want to use `scala.reflect.runtime` in real code, but it's extremely handy for investigations like this.)

When the compiler sees you trying to call `.point[ReaderInt]` on a type that doesn't have a `point` method—in this case `String`—it starts looking for implicit conversions that would convert a `String` into a type that does have a matching `point` method (this is called "enrichment" in Scala). We can see from the output of `showCode` that the implicit conversion it finds is a method called `ApplicativeIdV` in the `applicative` syntax object.

It then applies this conversion to the `String`, resulting in a value of type `ApplicativeIdV[String]`. This type's `point` method looks like this:

```
def point[F[_] : Applicative]: F[A] = Applicative[F].point(self)
```

Which is syntactic sugar for something like this:

```
def point[F[_]](implicit F: Applicative[F]): F[A] = F.point(self)
```

So the next thing it needs to do is find an `Applicative` instance for `F`. In your case you've explicitly specified that `F` is `ReaderInt`. It resolves the alias to `Reader[Int, _]`, which is itself an alias for `Kleisli[Id.Id, Int, _]`, and starts looking for an instance.

One of the first places it looks will be the `Kleisli` companion object, since it wants an implicit value of a type that includes `Kleisli`, and in fact `showCode` tells us that the one it finds is `Kleisli.kleisliIdMonadReader`. At that point it's done, and we get the `ReaderInt[String]` we wanted.

Comment: I didn't know about the reflection API. Nice. Even though I find both answers very good, I'll accept yours for teaching me how to fish ;)

Answer (score 4):

I wanted to update the former answer, but since you created separate question, I put it here.

**scalaz.syntax**

Let's consider the `point` example, and you can apply the same reasoning for other methods.

`point` (or haskell's `return`) or `pure`(just a type alias) belongs to `Applicative` trait. If you want to put something inside some `F`, you need at least `Applicative` instance for this `F`.

Usually, you will provide it implicitly with imports, but you can specify it explicitly as well.

In example from the first question, I assigned it to `val`

```
implicit val KA = scalaz.Kleisli.kleisliIdApplicative[Int]
```

because scala was not able to figure out the corresponding `Int` type for this applicative. In other words, it did not know Applicative for *which Reader* to bring in. (though sometimes compiler can figure it out)

For the Applicatives with one type parameter, we can bring implicit instances in just by using import

```
import scalaz.std.option.optionInstance 
import scalaz.std.list.listInstance
```

etc...

Okay, you have the instance. Now you need to invoke `point` on it.
You have few options:

**1. Access method directly**:

```
scalaz.std.option.optionInstance.point("hello")
KA.pure("hello")
```

**2. Explicitly pull it from implicit context**:

```
Applicative[Option].point("hello")
```

If you look into Applicative object, you would see

```
object Applicative {
  @inline def apply[F[_]](implicit F: Applicative[F]): Applicative[F] = F
}
```

Implementation of `apply`, is only returning the corresponding `Applicative[F]` instance for some type `F`.

So `Applicative[Option].point("hello")` is converted to
    `Applicative[Option].apply(scalaz.std.option.optionInstance)` 
which in the end is just `optionInstance`

**3. Use syntax**

```
import scalaz.syntax.applicative._
```

brings this method into implicit  scope:

```
  implicit def ApplicativeIdV[A](v: => A) = new ApplicativeIdV[A] {
    val nv = Need(v)
    def self = nv.value
  }

  trait ApplicativeIdV[A] extends Ops[A] {
    def point[F[_] : Applicative]: F[A] = Applicative[F].point(self)
    def pure[F[_] : Applicative]: F[A] = Applicative[F].point(self)
    def η[F[_] : Applicative]: F[A] = Applicative[F].point(self)
  }  ////
```

So then, whenever you try to invoke `point` on a `String`

```
"hello".point[Option]
```

compiler realizes, that `String` does not have the method `point` and begins to look through implicits, how it can get something which has `point`, from `String`.

It finds, that it can convert `String` to `ApplicativeIdV[String]`, which indeed has method `point`:

```
 def point[F[_] : Applicative]: F[A] = Applicative[F].point(self)
```

So in the end - your call desugares to

```
new ApplicativeIdV[Option]("hello")
```

More or less all typeclasses in scalaz are working the same way.
For `sequence`, the implementation is

```
def sequence[G[_]: Applicative, A](fga: F[G[A]]): G[F[A]] =
    traverse(fga)(ga => ga)
```

This colon after `G` means, that `Applicative[G]` should be provided implicitly.
It is essentialy the same as:

```
def sequence[G[_], A](fga: F[G[A]])(implicit ev: Applicative[G[_]]): G[F[A]] =
        traverse(fga)(ga => ga)
```

So all you need is the Applicative[G], and Traverse[F].

```
import scalaz.std.list.listInstance
import scalaz.std.option.optionInstance
Traverse[List].sequence[Option, String](Option("hello"))
```

Comment: Thanks for adding this explanation. A couple of minor remarks:
  - I guess you meant which in indeed has method `point`.
  -There's also a `]` missing in the implicit version of `sequence`.

Comment: ye, sorry messed that up a bit :). They both are aliases, so in this context you can use them interchangeably. I updated the post